# CSS - Page adapt on content height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a layout adaptable to dynamic content

What i want is that
`https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5uH1-IgLRWvN0dteDRROGFkWHc/view`

But if the content is dynamic and greather than the viewport, the left div gets smaller than content

How can i do this dynamically using only CSS? It's possible?

Follow the code:

HTML:

```
    <nav>
        <h2>Test</h2>
    </nav>
    <header>
        Test
    </header>
    <content>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-sEm9FgiMPbw/UI-pvvvC8wI/AAAAAAAABpo/L0kzBuQSePI/s1600/AngryRedBird.png"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-sEm9FgiMPbw/UI-pvvvC8wI/AAAAAAAABpo/L0kzBuQSePI/s1600/AngryRedBird.png"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-sEm9FgiMPbw/UI-pvvvC8wI/AAAAAAAABpo/L0kzBuQSePI/s1600/AngryRedBird.png"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-sEm9FgiMPbw/UI-pvvvC8wI/AAAAAAAABpo/L0kzBuQSePI/s1600/AngryRedBird.png"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-sEm9FgiMPbw/UI-pvvvC8wI/AAAAAAAABpo/L0kzBuQSePI/s1600/AngryRedBird.png"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-sEm9FgiMPbw/UI-pvvvC8wI/AAAAAAAABpo/L0kzBuQSePI/s1600/AngryRedBird.png"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-sEm9FgiMPbw/UI-pvvvC8wI/AAAAAAAABpo/L0kzBuQSePI/s1600/AngryRedBird.png"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-sEm9FgiMPbw/UI-pvvvC8wI/AAAAAAAABpo/L0kzBuQSePI/s1600/AngryRedBird.png"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-sEm9FgiMPbw/UI-pvvvC8wI/AAAAAAAABpo/L0kzBuQSePI/s1600/AngryRedBird.png"/></a>
    </content>
    <footer>
        Test
    </footer>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    html {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        height:100%;
    }
    body {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        height:100%;
    }
    nav {
        min-height:100%;
        background-color:red;
        float:left;
        width:16.67%;
    }
    header {
        min-height:5%;
        background-color:blue;
        float:left;
        width:83.33%;
    }
    content {
        min-height:95%;
        background-color:green;
        float:left;
        width:83.33%;
    }
    footer {
        min-height:5%;
        background-color:yellow;
        float:left;
        width:83.33%;
    }
    .clear {
        clear:both;
    }
```

Here the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzvkko4h/)

I tried everything, min-height, max-height, height,100%, 100vh, 100vmin

Someone can help me?

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve here but I did some coding.

Here it is: jsfiddle.net/alenm/z5eatg7b/

**Note:** I fix the navigation on the side.
Hope It will help you.

Comment: Isn't that i want. I want the nav stay with the same height from page without be fixed, i want to do a menu on this nav and this menu can be greater than user window :(